# dnlib - Смещение потока записи

Tags: c#, dnlib

При загрузке сборки я могу изменить позицию в файле и добавить свои данные, а затем сохранить

```
public static void WriteStream(string path, long offset, byte[] bytesArray)
{
   using FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
   stream.Position = offset;
   stream.Write(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);
}
```

Но, как можно записать их без загрузки файла через `FileStream` и сделать что-то непосредственно после `ModuleDefMD.Load(file);`.

Comment: `FileStream` ничего никуда не грузит, он открывант файловый дескриптор, чтобы вы могли читать или писать файл на диске. Уточните, в чём именно проблема.

Comment: Вот, а мне нужно загрузить не файловый дескриптор, а напрямую сделать смещение через загрузчик `ModuleDefMD.Load(file);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если глянуть в [исходники](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/master/src/DotNet/ModuleDefMD.cs), то видно что `Load` может грузить из массива байт.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
ms.Position = offset;
ms.Write(bytesArray);

ModuleDefMD.Load(bytes);
```

Или даже так

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesArray, 0, bytes, offset, bytesArray.Length);

ModuleDefMD.Load(bytes);
```